# how to get fullscreen for youtube api

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I just trying to set default allow  fullscreen for youtube api but i can't find that and  i am new  to javascript i tried so any many code but i didn't got.Actually i want to allow multiple youtube video  with full screen.

here's the code i am working

```
<div id="player"></div>
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>

<script>
    /**
     * Put your video IDs in this array
     */
    var videoIDs = [
        'MCgODvsmrmY',
        'RdyXFNgZdCw'
    ];

    var player, currentVideoId = 0;


    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            height: '350',
            width: '425',
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
            }
        });
    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
        node.requestFullScreen();

document.fullScreen; 

    }

    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
            currentVideoId++;
            if (currentVideoId < videoIDs.length) {
                player.loadVideoById(videoIDs[currentVideoId]);
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-button-fullscreen-enter").click();
}

</script>
```

Regards
madu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would work on the `document.fullScreen` line.

This [fullscreen demo](http://davidwalsh.name/fullscreen) from David Walsh (he's good) uses the following code:

```
// Find the right method, call on correct element
function launchIntoFullscreen(element) {
  if(element.requestFullscreen) {
    element.requestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if(element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if(element.msRequestFullscreen) {
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}

// Launch fullscreen for browsers that support it!
launchIntoFullscreen(document.documentElement); // the whole page
launchIntoFullscreen(document.getElementById("videoElement")); // any individual element
```

Comment: where to keep that code in  my code and should it open my youtube video in fullscreen by default?

Comment: I would have a new click event handler and put the fullscreen code from David in this. `$(".fullscreen-button").click(function() { launchInto... })`  The reason for this is that usually browsers don't allow fullscreen to be started without being wrapped inside a click event.  This is because browser vendors feel it's best if the user has control over fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted full screen of video either you calculated from embedded video or calculate ratio of video by height and width.

Note: New width will be constant

```
Example: if a video width = 300 and height = 270.
Ratio = width/height.
Say, your constant width_new = 200
height_new = width_new/Ratio
```